# Do I really need to create intermediate SQL tables if I use active record with ruby on rails?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I read a book and I from what I've seen I can't even think of one case that justifies using an intermediate SQL table to relate ID's as I was thought in University a good database design should have...the model specifies that kind of relations. I come fdrom the raw SQL world and now that I've discovered active record I don't see the need for relating id's on tables anymore. Am I wrong on this one?. If I am, please, enlighten me on why should I keep creating those intermediate SQL tables...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intermediate tables -- such as those with only foreign keys in them -- are necessary for many-to-many associations. For instance if you have a relationship between students and classes in which a student can belong to multiple classes and classes can have multiple students, then you'll need such a join table.

This is inherent in the relational database architecture, and is not changed by adding ActiveRecord to the mix. ActiveRecord can make it easy to ignore such intermediate tables when writing queries, but it needs to include them when building queries.

Consider how you would associate many students to classes that in turn have many students, without a join table. Either each student record would have to have multiple columns containing foreign keys to different classes, or multiple student records with the same data, but different foreign keys of a class would be needed. The first method would limit the number of associations to the number of foreign key columns. The second method would break the normalization of the database by storing the same data in multiple records.

By creating a join table instead, a student <-> class association can be recorded by simply adding a record to the join table. Any number of these associations can be created (up to the db table size limitation), and no data need be repeated.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of the classical approach. My question came from the point of if this was done in ruby code, but it's all clear now, I have to use a relation called has_many :through Association. For informative purposes I leave this:

A has_many :through association is often used to set up a many-to-many connection with another model. This association indicates that the declaring model can be matched with zero or more instances of another model by proceeding through a third model. For example, consider a medical practice where patients make appointments to see physicians.

Comment: The relevant association declarations could look like this:
class Physician < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :patients, through: :appointments
end
 
class Appointment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :physician
  belongs_to :patient
end
 
class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :physicians, through: :appointments
end

Comment: The corresponding migration might look like this:
class CreateAppointments < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :physicians do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
 
    create_table :patients do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
 
    create_table :appointments do |t|
      t.belongs_to :physician, index: true
      t.belongs_to :patient, index: true
      t.datetime :appointment_date
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end